# Ubuntu Serial Console Installer Encoding Issue

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, serial

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via serial console.  My PXE boot menu works fine, the initial load of the kernel into the ramdisk is legible, but as soon as the Ubuntu installer menu appears, it seems to switch to some strange character encoding that is illegible.

I have tried multiple terminal emulators, from VT100, xterm, ANSI
I have tried UTF-8, UTF-7, Western (ASCII) for my character encoding

Here's a sample line of text from the installer menu:
T␤␊ ⎽␊┌␊␌├␊␍ ┌⎺␌▒├␋⎺┼ ┬␋┌┌ ␉␊ ┤⎽␊␍ ├⎺ ⎽␊├ ≤⎺┤⎼ ├␋└␊ ≥⎺┼␊ ▒┼␍ ▒┌⎽⎺ °⎺⎼
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdUKG.jpg)

I thought it might be baud rate related, but it's not, as the ASCII box characters are all perfect.